# Java appletviewer on arm ubuntu

Tags: java, arm

I have an Ubuntu on arm CPU, where I would like to run a java applet standalone (i.e. not in the browser)

I have the iced tea plugin installed and it works in Firefox.

When I type `appletviewer applet.jar` it immediately exits without any message or window being opened.

How can I debug this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. The problem was that `appletviewer` was expecting a URL of an HTML file referencing the applet, passing the `.jar` file of the applet directly didn't work.
Try this `applet.html` file:

```
<applet
    archive="applet.jar"
    code="Your.applet.class.name.here.class"
    width="400"
    height="300"
>
</applet>
```

Note: The `<applet/>` element is deprecated, but it's the simplest way that I know to get an applet running in `appletviewer`. `appletviewer` doesn't care about HTML standards anyway.